# Handle messages one at time on python telebot

Tags: queue, telebot

i'm using a script (.bat) who do some download based on a link received on telegram, but at my code it can run multiple times, but i need to handle one message at time, and every message took like 15minutes to complete.

my atual code:

```
def handle_text_doc(message):
print ("bot new link to download")
with open ("test.txt","r") as arquivo:
    email = arquivo.read()
#print (email)

with open ("test.txt","w") as arquivo:
    texto = str(message) 
    arquivo.write(texto)
    
with open ("test.txt","r") as arquivo:
    email = arquivo.read()
    subprocess.call([r'c:\downloads\fullrun.bat'])
print ("terminado")
```

i need that subprocess finished before it starts again, but sometimes i receive like 10 messages, and i need to solve the .bat file for every messsage i receive, one at a time.

sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

So you should use async version of telebot - [click here to know more](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#asynchronous-telebot)

- Then your code should be something like this

```
async def handle_text_doc(message):
print ("bot new link to download")
await with open ("test.txt","r") as arquivo:
     await email = arquivo.read()
#print (email)

await with open ("test.txt","w") as arquivo:
    texto = str(message) 
    await arquivo.write(texto)
    
await with open ("test.txt","r") as arquivo:
    email = arquivo.read()
    await subprocess.call([r'c:\downloads\fullrun.bat'])
print ("terminado")
```